# Jquery/javascript image "pimping"

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation

I need to create a web application allowing people to upload an image and place on it a pre-defined element (like placing sunglasses on a face), with all necessary functionalities like resize, crop etc.

something like this: http://bayifier.com/

I can do that with flash, but i'm wondering if there s a way to do it with javascript.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could use canvas and javascript like [Pixastic](http://editor.pixastic.com/) does